# How to get proof using proof editor and checker

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, deduction

How can I use [Natural deduction proof editor and checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) or [The Logic Daemon](https://logic.tamu.edu/daemon.html) to derive the given conclusion from the given premise:

> (∃x) ( Fx ∙ (y) (Fy → y = x) )
>
> / (∃x) (y) (Fy ≡ y = x)

It tells me that my premise is not well formed. Anyone who knows how to use these tools, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first link here is a screenshot of how to enter the premise and conclusion:

[image]

Note that the FOL (First Order Logic) button is on, not the TFL (Truth Functional Logic) button.  The default is TFL. That would trigger a premise not being well formed message.

Note that "(y)" is entered as "Ay" without parentheses and with and "A".

Note there are no parentheses around "Ex".

Post a comment below if something isn't clear.

Here is a completion of the proof:

[image]

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: You also need to prove the converse for equivalence.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, I do see that a converse might be needed here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Using DC Proof 2.0** (another proof editor and checker)

**Color-coded variables**

- Black = bound variable
- Green = free variable to which either universal or existential
  generalizations may be applied
- Red = free variable to which only existential generalizations may be
  applied

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to this? I am also looking for a proof checker for modal logic.

Comment: DC Proof 2.0 is based on classical logic, but it is possible to define your axioms in it. Send me a full list of your axioms and I will see what I can do to get you started. To download DC Proof and for a contact link, visit my homepage.

Comment: I found the link on your profile and downloaded it.  Here is the link for others: http://www.dcproof.com/

Comment: @FrankHubeny  Apparently modal logic is just a working subset of FOL. See the answer to my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976552/how-does-modal-logic-differ-from-ordinary-predicate-logic So you should be able to do modal logic in DC Proof. You just have to avoid or restrict your use of the various rules of inference on the Logic menu.

Comment: Modal logic has its diamond and box inference rules, but from what I've seen of it used in Fitch's *Symbolic Logic* they have introduction and elimination rules as well. I haven't started using your product, but I would like to get familiar with it. I just started following your blog.

Comment: @FrankHubeny You can probably derive these axioms using the FOL representations of the diamond and box operators in DC Proof.

Comment: @FrankHubeny I was able to do so just now. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.logic/utNfhBjgowY

Comment: This is very interesting. You would be able to extend your proof checker to include various modal logics.

Comment: @FrankHubeny See the proofs at http://www.dcproof.com/AxiomOfModalLogicDerived.htm

Comment: I am going through the exercises in the tutorials of DC Proof with an intent to use this for modal logics. This might be an answer to a question I had earlier: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/55962/29944